# Formatação de números não está funcionando

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Tenho esse linha, onde preciso formatar um campo. Fiz de diversas formas e nada:

```
lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format("{0:N}", float.Parse(e.Total)));
```

e assim

```
lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format("{0:0.00}", float.Parse(e.Total)));
```

e mais assim

```
lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format("{0:0,0.00}", float.Parse(e.Total)));
```

Assim vem do banco: **205.728** e a saída deveria ser essa: **205,73** e está ficando assim: **205.728,00**

O método completo

```
public List<ItensLibDTO> getItensLib(int id)
        {
            var lista = contexto.ItensLibs
                .Where(itens => itens.IdOrcamento == id)
                .Select(item => new ItensLibDTO
                {
                    Produto = item.Produto,
                    Qtde = item.Qtde.ToString(),
                    Unitario = item.Unitario.ToString(),
                    Custo = item.Custo.ToString(),
                    CustoDiario = item.CustoDiario.ToString(),
                    UltCondicao = item.UltCondicao.ToString(),
                    Total = item.Total.ToString()
                }).ToList();

            lista.ForEach(e => e.UltCondicao = new DateTime(1800, 12, 28).AddDays(float.Parse(e.UltCondicao)).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
            lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = string.Format("{0:N}", float.Parse(e.Total)));

            return lista;
        }
```

Comment: Qual o tipo de `item.Unitario`?

Comment: @LINQ, double. Todos os valores monetários são double. Resolvi acompanhar o banco. Pensei em jogar para decimal, mas deixei como está.

Comment: Ok, remova os `.ToString` dentro da consulta. Se você quer manter campos como `string` para depois poder alterar, sugiro que tenha duas vezes cada campo então. Aquele `ToString` vai confundir tudo.

Comment: Não entendi. Me deu um nó. Como assim duas vezes?

Comment: Vamos do começo. Por que vocês pôs `ToString` nos campos numéricos?

Comment: Os campos do DTO são string e da minha Model são numéricos. Tive uns problemas, que discuti bastante aqui no site e ainda não obtive resposta. sempre que enviava os campos como numéricos, exceto INT e Decimal, dava erro de Cast. A forma encontrada para contornar isso, foi passar os campos da DTO para string e assim fiz e por isso estou conseguindo trabalhar. Falei até que uma gambi, mas foi o que eu consegui fazrr.

Comment: Isso tá uma bagunça, @pnet. Postei a solução

Comment: Você conseguiu solucionar o problema? Alguma resposta te ajudou nisso ou falta algum detalhe?

Comment: Havia marcado sua resposta. Agora pude ver que não marcou. Mas resolveu sim a forma que vc havia feito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só pra deixar registrado, isso que você tá fazendo é uma confusão enorme e, baseado nisto, pode-se dizer que seus problemas não vão terminar por aqui. O correto deveria ser resolver o problema do início e começar a fazer tudo corretamente.

Dado o aviso legal, vamos à solução. O problema aqui é que o número está no formato americano, a partir daí começa a bagunça com culturas.

O que você precisa fazer é **converter o número para `double`** usando o formato original e depois converter para `string` novamente, desta vez usando o formato que você deseja na apresentação.

```
string.Format(new CultureInfo("pt-BR"), "{0:N}", 
              double.Parse("250.728", new CultureInfo("en").NumberFormat));
```

Comment: Sei que está uma bagunça sim e reconheço. O problema é que eu não consegui resolver o problema e estava patinando, patinando, então fiz essa "gambi" para poder avançar. Sei que é o que deveria ser, mas foi o que deu. Ainda estou tentando resolver, mas sempre dá erro de cast  e não vai nem com reza "braba".

Comment: @pnet Ah, sim. Tranquilo, foi um aviso pq me senti na obrigação de dizer. De qualquer forma, a solução pro problema desta pergunta é isso que eu postei.

Comment: Relaxa, se tá ruim tem que falar sim, aqui é pra isso. Eu gosto disso, quando me dizem o que realmente está acontecendo. Tem um colega aqui, que quando ele ve isso, desse a "lenha" e acho isso bacana sim.

Comment: resolveu dessa forma a questão. O problema estava então no padrão americano.

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso, você pode juntar a classe [`CultureInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) com o método [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
lista.ForEach(e => e.Total = float.Parse(e.Total).ToString("0.00").Replace(".", ","));
```

Não se esqueça de adicionar o uso do namespace onde se encontra a classe CultureInfo:

```
using System.Globalization;
```

**Explicação:**

*`new CultureInfo("pt-BR")`*: Formata o texto de acordo com o padrão brasileiro, ou seja, com virgula nos números que possuem casas decimais.

*`"0.00"`*: Indica que o texto deve ter somente 2 casas decimais.

Comment: Não funcionou, ficou assim: `<Total>205728,00</Total>`. Ele está entendendo o ponto do float como separador de milhar e o pont é equivalente a vírgula. Como fazer ele entender isso?

Comment: @pnet [Aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q6ivF8) ta nos trincos.

Comment: Então, tenta formatar essa string, da forma que eu estou postando: 205.728. lembre-se, isso é uma string, faça o parse para float e depois formata. Essa string seria equivalente a: 205,728, mas ela está recebendo ponto e não vírgula.

Comment: @pnet Editei a resposta, da uma olhada.

Comment: Cara, tá osso isso aqui. Veja o resultado no browser: `<Total>205728,00</Total>`

Comment: @pnet Desisto kkkk

Comment: Fiz conforme o exemplo acima e funcionou. Você estava certo, apenas faltou uma segunda CultureInfo, pois o formato numérico é o americano(Vide Linq). Dessa forma funcionou. Mas é assim mesmo. Eu tenho uns posts sobre Cast, que até agora tá sem solução.